# more than one validation, confusing

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vee-validate

I'm currently used `vee-validate` to check my input, and in this case I need you to check two things, first the function that has already added, the length of the value should der example of `length: 2`, perfect, but Now I need to check that the value entered is not repeated.

I currently keep in my backend all the IDs that have already been reported, I need to validate that the ID that the person writes is not `!==` and any existing in my database which are in the Array `idPayExist`

I'm confused as to associate the v-model or tell `vee-validate` ok compare with this matris, I thank the help.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/codeflyin/eywraw8t/484172/)

Good day and blessings for all.

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.use(VeeValidate);

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
   tx: '',
    idPayExist: [01,12,55,13,20,65]
  },
  methods: {
 
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.2/css/bulma.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vee-validate@latest/dist/vee-validate.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <div class="column">
      <div class="control">
        <label class="label">ID Pay</label>
        <input class="input" v-model="tx" v-validate="'length:2'" name="atex" type="number" autocomplete="off" required />
       </div>
       <p class="help is-danger">{{ errors.first('atex') }}</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation you should be able to  assign multiple rules

```
<input class="input" v-model="tx" v-validate="{length: 2, included: idPayExists}">
```

From the docs:

> WARNING
>   Client-side validation is never a substitute for server-side validation. Make sure to validate any input from the user on your backend as well.

So in fact you shouldn't just rely on this to validate your fields, that's why it doesn't matter that you're binding the value with v-model. VeeValidate just checks the value of the input even when you don't use `v-model`.